# How can we detect these points in this case?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a data of pulse train samples as amplitude samples with equal intervals.

Let's call the sampled pulse amplitude array as A and time array as t.
So the plot is obtained by plot(t, A) in MATLAB.

Here below is plot of the pulse train:

[image]

And below is the zoomed version(green dots are samples, reds circles are max points):

[image]

What I need to do is, I need an algorithm which can detect and save the max point of each pulse(I circled them in red above) into an array.

So far I tried the following but didn't work:

```
kk = 0
for i=1:length(t)-2
        if y(i)>0 & y(i+1)>y(i) & y(i+2)>y(i+1) & y(i+3)<y(i+2)
            kk = kk+1;
            maxPointTime(kk) = t(i+2);
            maxPointVoltage(kk)  = A(i+2);
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the local maxima, right? MATLAB has a build in function to do so, cf. [doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/islocalmax.html).

```
x = 1:100;
A = (1-cos(2*pi*0.01*x)).*sin(2*pi*0.15*x);
TF = islocalmax(A);
plot(x,A,x(TF),A(TF),'r*')
```